# How to set a value for the input type 'datetime-local'?

Tags: php, html, datetime, datetime-format

I tried this:

```
<input type="datetime-local"  value="<?php echo $row['Time']; ?>" class="date" name="start" REQUIRED>
```

How can I set the value of this input field with the data from the database?
It doesn't work!!
I need to make it possible to edit too.
Or should I use another type of input?
`$row['Time']` is from the database!

Comment: Write what's in `$row['Time'];`

Comment: You need to give more context, rather than just say "it doesn't work". In what way doesn't it work? What are you using to serve the page? What web browser are you using? What are you expecting to see? What example / documentation were you following that led you to trying this?

Comment: Check my solution, if it will work accept my answer :) Thanks!

Comment: $row['Time'] got the value : 2016-11-18 12:00:00

Comment: Check now I have updated my answer, with how to do it in your code.

Comment: @KarolGasienica it seems good, but its not working, it doesn't fill in the value

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I don't know exacly what is in `$row['Time']` but it should be as follows:

**Definition**

> A valid date-time as defined in **RFC 3339** with these
>   additional qualifications:
>
> - the literal letters T and Z in the date/time syntax must always be uppercase
> - the date-fullyear production is instead defined as four or more digits representing a number greater than 0
>
> **Examples**
>
> - 1990-12-31T23:59:60Z
> - 1996-12-19T16:39:57-08:00

---

**Solution**

To create **RFC 3339** format in PHP you can use:

```
echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP', $row['Time']);
```

or in another way:

```
echo date("c", strtotime($row['Time']));
```

or if you prefer objective style:

```
echo (new DateTime($row['Time']))->format('c');
```

---

**In your code**

So in your code it would look as follows:

```
<input type="datetime-local"  value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP', $row['Time']); ?>" class="date" name="start" REQUIRED>
```

or

```
<input type="datetime-local"  value="<?php echo date("c", strtotime($row['Time'])); ?>" class="date" name="start" REQUIRED>
```

---

**Manual**

- More informations can be found [here](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.datetime.html#input.datetime.attrs.value)
- [PHP date Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)
- [PHP DateTime Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)

Comment: It does not fill in the value, it only works when i do this:                       `<input type="datetime-local"  value="1985-04-12T23:20:50.52" class="date" name="start" REQUIRED>`

Comment: I see there is a dot before second. So may it will work: `echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $row['Time']);`

Comment: Im not using seconds, It still doesn't work.  `<input type="datetime-local" value="1985-04-12T23:20" class="date" name="start" REQUIRED>`

Comment: Did you try that `echo`? What's that `.52` at the end then?

Comment: It must be this: <input type="datetime-local" value="1985-04-12T23:20" class="date" name="start" REQUIRED> this works, but when i add PHP code then it doesn't work

Comment: vote 1 up please on my question so i can earn a badge.  I Found an answer already, when u vote my question up, ill accept your answer.

Comment: Done ;) I would be grateful for accepting my answer.

Comment: I had the same problem, and your solution worked, just without the P: `echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $time);`

Comment: try this <input type="datetime-local"  value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i', $row['Time']); ?>" class="date" name="start" REQUIRED>

Comment: It seems to depend on the Browser: Your Solutions do not work in my Chromium:
https://caniuse.com/mdn-html_elements_input_input-datetime-local

Comment: `date("c")` provides a timezone and therefore does not work.

Answer (score 34):

When submitting `<form>` using `<input type="datetime-local">`

the value format you will get is look like this.

> 2019-09-06T00:21

To set new value in your input type box.

You must use:

```
date('Y-m-d\TH:i', strtotime($exampleDate)) //2019-08-18T00:00
```

**Solution Example**:

```
$exampleDate = "2019-08-18 00:00:00"; //sql timestamp
$exampleDate = strtotime($exampleDate); //convert to unix timestamp 
$newDate = date('Y-m-d\TH:i', $exampleDate); //format unix to date
```

or

```
$exampleDate = "2019-08-18 00:00:00";//sql timestamp
$newDate = date('Y-m-d\TH:i', strtotime($exampleDate));
```

If you don't use `strtotime()` you will get an error of

> Notice: A non well formed numeric value encountered

---

**Tested**:

```
 - $exampleDate = 2019-08-18 00:00:00 ;
 - //Not Working - output(1970-01-01T01:33:39)
 - <?php echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $exampleDate);?>
 - //Not Working - output(1970-01-01T01:33:39+01:00)
 - <?php echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP', $exampleDate);?>
 - //Not Working - output(2019-08-18T00:00:00+02:00)
 - <?php echo date("c", strtotime($exampleDate));?>
 - //Not Working - output(2019-09-23T19:36:01+02:00)
 - <?php echo (new DateTime($row['Time']))->format('c');?>
 - //Working Perfect - output(2019-08-18T00:00:00)
 - <?php echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', strtotime($exampleDate));?>
```

Comment: @MdRehan Glad to help.

Answer (score 10):

it's simple is that and working for me 
first convert your php value to this format

```
 <?php  $datetime = new DateTime($timeinout[0]->time_in);   ?>
```

then in value of html input element 
use this format

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="txt_time_in" placeholder="Time In" name="timein" value = "<?php echo $datetime->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s'); ?>" class="form-control" />
```

this will set your value to input element

Answer (score 8):

The answer of Karol Gasienica is a great explanation but somehow did not work for me even in their replies

```
date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', $row['Time']); //Gives me 1970-01-01 00:00
date('Y-m-d\TH:i:sP', $row['Time']); //Gives me no display
date("c", strtotime($row['Time'])); //No display too
```

What worked for me is this

```
$t = $row['Time'];
date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', strtotime($t)); // This got it perfectly
```

However I still voted it up becauce of the explanation.

Answer (score 6):

None of the above solutions worked for me as of 2019 using Google Chrome `Version 78.0.3904.70 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

What worked for me is.

```
<input type="datetime-local" value="2017-06-13T13:00">
```

As you can see the format is `2017-06-13T13:00` or `Y-m-dTH:i`.

As of PHP you can do like.

```
<input type="datetime-local" value="<?php echo Date('Y-m-d\TH:i',time()) ?>">
```

Hope this will save someone's time. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
date('Y-m-d\TH:i'); //Example result: '2017-01-01T01:01'
```

if use \T instead of T (not working)

```
date('Y-m-dTH:i'); //Example result: '2017-01-01UTC01:01'
```

Answer (score 2):

Better use timezone feature

```
function getCurrentDateTime(){
    $date = new DateTime();
    $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('GMT+6')); //Time Zone GMT +6
    $dt= $date->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s');
    return $dt;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try that. I get that in Bootstrap 4. (Google Translate: prueba con eso, a mi me sale con eso en Bootstrap 4. )

```html
<input class="form-control" type="datetime-local" name="fecha_e" id="fecha_e" value=" 
<?php echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i', strtotime($data['fecha_e_tarea'])); ?>" required>
```

Comment: Please post in English

Comment: Please use in English.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please write your answer in English, as Stack Overflow is an [English only site](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680).

Answer (score 1):

The simple way working for me is

```
<input  type="datetime-local"  value="<?= str_replace(' ', 'T', $date) ?>" name="date"  required />
```

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way! Here's how to set a value using php for input field with type="datetime-local"
setting value using php in type="datetime-local"

```
$date_now_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('+5 hours'));
$from_for_val=  date("Y-m-d\TH:i:s", strtotime($date_now_time));
```

Below is html form input field with type="datetime-local" and its showing how to set value inside input field

```
   <input type="datetime-local" name="submit_from" value="<?=$from_for_val;?>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$tripid=$_REQUEST['tripid'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM tripdetails WHERE trip_id='".$tripid."'";
$trpresult=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
  if(mysqli_num_rows($trpresult)==1)
    {
      $trpdetails=mysqli_fetch_assoc($trpresult);
    }
 $trpstartdate = substr_replace($trpdetails['trip_start_date'],T,11,0);

 $string = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $trpstartdate);
```

> This is Html part

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="trip_start_date" id="cal" value="<?php echo $string?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

This will convert datetime from database to datetime-local

`str_replace(" ","T",substr_replace($string ,"", -3))`

Answer (score 0):

**Try it:**

```
<input type="datetime-local"  value="<?php $row['Time'] = preg_replace("/\s/",'T',$row['Time']); echo $row['Time']?>" class="date" name="start" REQUIRED>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

for everybody on 2021 the working format is `Y-m-d\TH:i`
all other old format is just a hussel.
if you are using carbon library

```
 \Carbon\Carbon::parse($data->chosen_date,$timezone)->format('Y-m-d\TH:i')
```

after that you can just pass to value like this
if are using ajax or fetch api

```
document.getElementById('chosen_date').value = data.chosen_date
```