# Assigning default value to Form::input('dateTime-local')

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I'm trying to create my edit event page, so i want to place the database value in a Form::input('dateTime-local') but all it gets is the default placeholder.

My events.edit view

```
{{ Form::input('dateTime-local', 'startDate', $event->startDate, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

The EventController

```
public function viewEdit($id) {
   $event = Event::find($id); 
   return view('events.edit',compact('event')); 
}
```

The database

```
id | startDate | endDate | email | phoneNumber | entraceCost | address | city_id | created_at | updated_at

5 | 4657-03-06 05:47:00 | 5677-04-07 07:59:00 | fas@dasf.pt | 123456789 | 0.00 | artgwergbertgergtergerg4352 | 5 | 2017-07-28 11:17:14 | 2017-07-28 11:17:14
```

Your help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the datetime in a specific format. Send this date variable in your controller:

```
$dt = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $event->startDate);
$date = $dt->format('Y-m-d\TH:i'));
```

And in the view:

```
{{ Form::input('dateTime-local', 'startDate', $date, array('class' => 'form-control')) }}
```

Check this question for reference: [How can i set a value for the input type 'datetime-local'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40843407/how-can-i-set-a-value-for-the-input-type-datetime-local)

Comment: my form input still has the default placeholder "dd/mm/aaa --:--" it didn't work.

Comment: What's the result of `dd($event->startDate);`?

Comment: "4657-03-06 05:47:00"

Comment: ty  Laerte you made me see the problem.

Comment: I can't check rigth now but when i have access to the project again i'll check it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

got the problem "4657-03-06T05:47:00+00:00" does not match the pattern pretended by the input.

I need to pass to the value "4657-03-06T05:47".