# Datetime value in the input field

Tags: php, datetime

I have a problem echoing the DateTime in the input field with PHP. Now I cannot echo the selected DateTime value in the input field.

Below is my sample coding, I use below method cannot echo selected value:

```html
<?php
$datetime ="2021-06-04 09:13:00";
?>
<input type="datetime-local" class="form-control" id="datetime" name="datetime" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d\TH:i:s', strtotime($datetime));?> ">
```

The result shows me like below picture:

[image: output1]

This is my online working sample code : https://paiza.io/projects/D-J1uBPeHJuL8jCOhToRQQ

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: I think this is duplicate question, You can follow this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40843407/how-to-set-a-value-for-the-input-type-datetime-local

Comment: I have followed, but the result can't show. You can try.

Comment: If you try this html, it will display the date and time <input type=datetime-local value="2018-02-27T21:10">
So you should make your php code as above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may follow like this

```
<?php
// Ajmal Praveen

$datetime ="2021-06-04T09:13:00";
?>
<input type="datetime-local" value="<?php echo $datetime; ?>">
```

It will work. You need to Include the T, between date and time

Comment: variable value cannot change. Because it will come from database in the future.

Comment: So you can do one thing, 2021-06-04 <- count the char So its 10, after the 10th char add T using STR replace between the Date and time. Little more coding is seriously required to make it working for sure.

Comment: Can you give me sample on your answer?

Answer (score -1):

**PHP To Modify Existing Date time from Database using HTML5 Datetime-local**
I written this function mainly to get work the HTML5 Datetime, it can be used with any of script.

```
<?php
// Code by Ajmal Praveen
 $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
// Used Current Date time
 $GetDate = date("c", strtotime($time));
 list($Date) = explode('+', $GetDate);
 $GetDate = $Date;
// Code by Ajmal Praveen
 //Output
 ?>
 <input type="datetime-local" value="<?php echo $GetDate; ?>">
```

If the code is useful Do a Upvote. Thank you.